# Acitvate the "user x is typing..." status in python telethon

Tags: python, telethon

I have this code to implement ChatGPT into a Telegram User Account.

```
# Import necessary libraries
import telethon
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
from telethon.tl.types import SendMessageTypingAction
import random
import time
import openai

# Set your OpenAI API key
openai.api_key = "key"

# Initialize the Telegram client with your API ID and hash
api_id = "id"  # Replace with your API ID
api_hash = "hash"  # Replace with your API hash
client = TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash)

# Initialize a TinyDB database to store user conversations
db = TinyDB('db.json')
Telegram = Query()

# Read the chat bot prompt from a file
with open('path to prompt', 'r') as f:
    chat_bot_prompt = f.read()

# Register an event handler for incoming messages
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handle_new_message(event):
    before_time = time.time()
    # Get the username and message from the event
    username = event.message.sender_id
    message = event.message.text

    # Check if the user is new or has an existing conversation
    if not (db.search(Telegram.username == username)):
        # If the user is new, start a new conversation
        conversation : list[str] = []
        conversation.append(message)
        
        # Generate a response using the GPT-3.5 Turbo model
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model='gpt-3.5-turbo',
            messages=[{'role': 'system', 'content': chat_bot_prompt}, {'role': 'user', 'content': message}],
            temperature=0
        )
        reply = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
        conversation.append(reply)
        
        # Store the conversation in the database
        db.insert({'username': username, 'conversation': conversation})
    else:
        # If the user has an existing conversation, continue it
        user = db.search(Telegram.username == username)
        conversation = user[0]['conversation']
        conversation.append(message)
        messages : list = [{'role': 'system', 'content': chat_bot_prompt}]
        
        # Prepare the conversation history for GPT-3.5 Turbo
        for i in range(len(conversation)):
            if (i % 2 == 0):
                messages.append({'role': 'user', 'content': conversation[i]})
            else:
                messages.append({'role': 'assistant', 'content': conversation[i]})
        
        # Generate a response using the GPT-3.5 Turbo model
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model='gpt-3.5-turbo',
            messages=messages,
            temperature=0
        )
        reply = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
        conversation.append(reply)
        
        # Update the conversation in the database
        db.update({'conversation': conversation}, Telegram.username == username)
    
    print(f"Received a message from {username}: {message}, Replied with: {reply}")

    # Calculate the delay based on the length of the reply
    delay = len(reply) / 6 - (time.time() -  before_time)

    if (delay < 0):
        delay = 0

    # Simulate typing by setting the 'typing' action
    async with client.action(event.chat_id, 'typing'):
        time.sleep(delay)

    # Send the reply with the calculated delay
    await event.respond(reply)

# Start the Telegram client
client.start()

# Run the client until Ctrl+C is pressed
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

I wanted to make it more human like to simulate the "user x is typing..." status with this part of the code

```
async with client.action(event.chat_id, 'typing'):
    time.sleep(delay)
```

but it just doesn't work. It doesn't display the status in the profile when I'm chatting with the Bot. I get no errors, but it just doesn't work. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep` blocks the entire thread, meaning the `asyncio` event loop cannot run, meaning Telethon requests won't be sent.

You need to use `await asyncio.sleep(delay)` instead.